# Populating jstree threeview from angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstree

So far I've done 90% of what I had to do with my very limited front-end skills so I now need help.

I'm using [jstree](https://github.com/vakata/jstree) to build treview and it works fine for static data (the one in `else` block) as shown below.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#list").jstree({
            "core": {
                "data": function (node, cb) {
                    if (node.id === "#") {
                        cb([{
                            "text": "Root",
                            "state": {"opened": true},
                            "children": true
                        }]);
                    } else {
                        // This is the one I am try to populate dynamicaly
                        cb([{"id":"1","text":"Lis 1"},{"id":"2","text":"Lis 2"}]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I now need to populate `else` block with dynamic result-set coming from angular variable `vm.list` (*available to dump with* `{{ vm.list }}` *in HTML page*) so how can I do it? The documentation has some details about population data dynamically ([html](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-a-tree-using-html), [array/json](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-a-tree-using-an-array-or-json), [ajax](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-ajax), [lazy load](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-ajax-and-lazy-loading-nodes) and [callback](https://github.com/vakata/jstree#populating-the-tree-using-a-callback-function)) but nothing like I need.

Passing `vm` as third param in callback function and changing `else` block to `cb(vm.cat);` didn't do the trick. If my front-end knowledge wasn't at the rock bottom, I would have come up with better tries!

My angular controller looks like:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = ['$on', '$timeout', 'listService',
    function($on, $timeout, listService) {
        var vm = this;
        ....
        load();
        ....

        function load() {
            // This is actually coming from an API and massive
            vm.cat = [{'id':'1', 'text':'Lis 1'}, {'id':'2', 'text':'Lis 2'}];
        };
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution but don't like it so I'll wait for someone with better solution otherwise I'll regrettably accept this as it dumps content into a DOM element and reads its content to create the tree which is a bit hacky and heavy in my opinion.

```
<div id="data" style="display: none">{{ vm.cat }}</div>


$(function() {
    var data = $('#data').text();
    if (data) {
        $("#list").jstree({
            "core": {
                "data": JSON.parse(data)
            }
        });
    }
});
```